# cookies is not persist in IE,but working fine with Chome

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using the code below to add and update cookies:

```
public ActionResult SaveUserTypeCookies(string usertype)
{
    if (Request.Cookies["User"] != null)
    {
        HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["User"];
        cookie.Values["UserType"] = usertype;
        cookie.Expires = DateTime.MaxValue;
        Response.SetCookie(cookie);
    }
    else
    {
        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("User");
        //Need to remove below comment at production deployement
        //cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        //cookie.Secure = true;
        cookie.Values["UserType"] = usertype;
        cookie.Expires = DateTime.MaxValue;
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    }
    return RedirectToAction("CreateUpsID");
}
```

And I'm using the code below to check for the existence of cookies:

```
 @if (!(Request.Cookies["User"] != null))
{
    <div id="overlay_div" class="overlay"></div>
}
```

I used

```
@if (!(Request.Cookies["User"] != null))
```

instead of

```
@if ((Request.Cookies["User"] == null))
```

to avoid any automatic reset to null.

This code is working fine with Chrome, but when I am using IE11, cookies don't persist.

Comment: How do you know cookies don't persist? Are you debugging the code directly or are you checking in the browser dev tools?

Comment: In side if condition,i have putted a div, if cookies is null than div displays.

Comment: Are cookies enabled in IE11? http://www.technipages.com/ie-enable-disable-cookies also can you try adding your current domain to the trusted sites to ensure it's not a security issue. Your code looks OK and the fact it's working in one browser makes it sound like a browser configuration or security issue. Can you try Firefox/Safari also or IE on a different machine?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion,but i have tried to enable cookies ,it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried debugging the code in Visual Studio?